# Base class (Domain Model) conversion to derived class (View Model)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I see the following pattern in an MVC app where basically a derived class has added minor functionality to a domain class, many times just display readonly properties that are dependent on other properties from base class. What would be the better way to not have to write the very basic properties copy code (`between //***** //*****`)?

```
//Can't change this class, it has what is shown (it contains only properties)
public class MyDomainModel
{
    public bool BoolValue { get; set; }

    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int Prop2 { get; set; }
    // Several other properties
}

public class MyViewModel : MyDomainModel
{
    // This is the only property that is added to the view model class
    public string DisplayValue
    {
        get { return BoolValue ? "Value1" : "Value2"; }
    }

    public static MyViewModel FromBase(MyDomainModel myDomainModel)
    {
        var myViewModel = new MyViewModel();

        //*****
        myViewModel.BoolValue = myDomainModel.BoolValue;
        myViewModel.Prop1 = myDomainModel.Prop1;
        myViewModel.Prop2 = myDomainModel.Prop2;
        // Several other properties
        //*****

        return myViewModel;
    }
}

// some other place

MyDomainModel myDomainObject = CallService();

//Here MyDomainModel needs to be converted to MyViewModel
MyViewModel myViewObject = MyViewModel.FromBase(myDomainObject);
```

**EDIT:** I wanted this question to address the concern of too much "attribute copying" code spread across the application. Unfortunately, the wrong choice of example (ViewModel derived from DomainModel) led the discussion in another territory.

Comment: What is your goal ? You just want to extend the functionality of the class ? Or do you actually want to make other instances with varying functionality ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> public class MyDomainModel
> {
>     // .....
> }
>
> public class MyViewModel : MyDomainModel
> {
>     // .....
> }
> ```

Why would you have your View Model inherit your Domain Model?  **This seems like a *terrible* idea.**

What benefit does inheritance give you in this situation?  What are you re-using?

All I can see is a bag of properties, and in your usage scenario you can't even reuse those (since you get an already instantiated base class and you cannot change the instantiation of that to a derived class).

An axiom that seems appropriate here (and often) is "favor composition over inheritance".  Unless you have a clear reason and benefit to inheritance, avoid it.

The most common advice is to make your ViewModels completely separate classes and keep them dependency free.  They should be simple POCO's.

Then, you simply map your domain model object to your view model object.  This will involve some repetitive property copying code or use of a tool like AutoMapper, but you *want* the duplication here as it reduces coupling.

Inheriting, on the other hand, introduces some terribly tight coupling that will almost certainly cause you problems.

Comment: Nice post, thanks. The app is doing composition in most of the places, especially when complex transformation is needed but in many other places it using this pattern also when the view model is identical to the domain model. Also, I wanted to keep the question focused to the way to avoid the "repetitive property copying code". The MyDomainObject that I used in the example, is actually plain DTO that is populated from REST service. In the service layer also the similar things happen where the domain models populate the DTOs. The apps are filled with "repetitive property copying code".

Comment: Have used AutoMapper in some places but most places still have the same repetitive code. I guess we should use AutoMapper more and more.

Answer (score 0):

Create a copy-constructor in the base.

That will save you a lot of code in the derived classes.

```
public class MyDomainModel
{
    public bool BoolValue { get; set; }

    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int Prop2 { get; set; }

    public MyDomainModel(MyDomainModel myDomainModel)
    {
        var myViewModel = new MyViewModel();

        //*****
        this.BoolValue = myDomainModel.BoolValue;
        this.Prop1 = myDomainModel.Prop1;
        this.Prop2 = myDomainModel.Prop2;
        // Several other properties
        //*****
    }
}

public class MyViewModel : MyDomainModel
{
    // This is the only property that is added to the view model class
    public string DisplayValue
    {
        get { return BoolValue ? "Value1" : "Value2"; }
    }

    public MyViewModel (MyDomainModel other) : base(other) {}
}
```

Then in the code use:

```
// some other place

MyDomainModel myDomainObject = CallService();

//Here MyDomainModel needs to be converted to MyViewModel
MyViewModel myViewObject = new MyViewModel(myDomainObject);
```

Comment: And then how exactly are you supposed to instantiate a `MyViewModel` filled in with an existing `MyDomainModel`?

Comment: Can't update the domain class, I mentioned that in the question. But even if that is feasible, the only affect it has it to move the monotonous "copy properties" code from derived to base class. It still has to be written.

Comment: umm .. you do realize that's not valid right?  Constructors aren't inherited.

Comment: @qes : Lol, forgot the declaration in the inherited object.. will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This looks similar to a pattern where you want to attach information to all models before rendering the view. You can actually do this by overriding OnActionExecuted and then attaching data to your model.

```
 protected override OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
 {
      ViewResult viewResult = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;

      if(viewResult != null)
      {
           MyDomainModel model = viewResult.ViewData.Model as MyDomainModel;

           if(model != null)
              /* Set Properties on your Model, for any model deriving 
                 from MyDomainModel! */
      }
 }
```

Comment: I guess not. First, the information is custom per view model. Second, the view models are reused and it might be better to keep this kind of simple logic within the view model instead of being spread in the controllers. For complex transformations from domain model to view model is taken care of custom code and that is fine. It is for simple transformation like one shown above, it seems like too much code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are violate Single Responsibility Principle because the Responsibility to ViewModel is just to present the some data from domain model for view without any business logic in this classes view model classes usually represents
a DTO object and you can map the data for Domain object into ViewModel object use the 
[AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)

look at the following articles examples [Automaper NerdDinner](http://mhinze.com/2009/07/06/automapper-in-nerddinner/)

[AutoMapper: the Object-Object Mapper](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/01/23/automapper-the-object-object-mapper/)